# Selenium get currently active tab

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, tabs

It's possible to get current active tab in firefox using selenium?
I'm creating app which is half-automated (user is opening tabs and if he wants to dump one of them he just clicks hot-key).

But I have problem when user opens multiple tabs, I need to know to which one I should switch to dump site.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the originally opened window, then you can have your app switch to it.

```
var OriginalWHND = Driver.GetWindowHandles()[0];

...

// when you need to switch back..
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(OriginalWHND);
```

Comment: But the problem is that user switch tab (in window) but driver is still focued on startup tab. I need to detect active tab to be able switch driver to it.

Comment: Ok, got it. Now I'm scanning browser memory to get value which holds active tab index.